# Error: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType after doing "docker-compose up -d"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I'm doing a school work, where i need to user a docker-compose.yml file to simulate day in a life of a Dev Ops employee. I'm having this error after doing "docker-compose up -d"

[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfB34.png)

I have found some answers but they are for really different files than mine, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Wrong indentation at "services:". Also avoid screenshots of source code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: okey,, sorry about that im new in here.